# Corodva error running iOS

Tags: jquery, cordova, terminal, npm

**Help! I Cordova does not start, worked yesterday, but today is not! Pereustanoka not helped**

```
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/index.css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/img
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/index.html
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/.DS_Store
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/index.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www

mkdir: path already exists: /Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www

cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/css/.DS_Store

cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/mark/intuition/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/www/statusbar.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:977:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:149:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:127:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:93:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:104:25
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
```

Comment: Have you logged in with a new user than yesterday? The error says that cordova cannot access the directory. You need to log in as Admin or change the file permissions. If you are on linux/unix than to change file permissions use the command `chmod 777 <name of the directory/file>` after loggin in as root/admin.

Comment: @frank in this situation helps to drag the project to Cordoba in the new directory. But I tried it and that's your soposb works too!)

Comment: Can you make sure that the required environment variables are NOT modified? re-check npm, JDK and Ant variables ?

Comment: If it is possible, try to remove the environment(iOS) and re-add it again and test.